# Display a pop up UI based on users' answer

Tags: google-apps-script

I currently have a UI with drop down questions.  When a user select a certain answer in the drop down list, I want to show another UI that will allow the user to answer more questions. Then, I would like to close this window and return the user to the first UI and continue answering questions.

I have tried popuppanel, set one Ui's invisibility to false but nothing seems to work.

NOTE: Since the data in my first UI are dynamic, I can't use the GUI builder so please only provide solutions using code.

These are the code I have so far:

```
// when user select this drop down option, show another UI
case 'Move to a special meeting':
  displayActionItemsUI();
  cellStatus.offset(numOfRowsOffset,0).setValue(N);
  cellMeetingType.offset(numOfRowsOffset,0).setValue('Special Meeting');
  break;


function displayActionItemsUI() {

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var panelActionItems = app.createVerticalPanel();

  var gridActionItems = app.createGrid(3, 2).setId('gridActionItems')
      .setCellPadding(15);

  var lblTaskStatement = app.createLabel('Task Statement:');
  var lblOwner = app.createLabel('Owner:');
  var lblDeadline = app.createLabel('Deadline:');

  var tboxTask = app.createTextBox().setId('tboxTask').setName('tboxTask');
  var tboxOwner = app.createTextBox().setId('tboxOwner').setName('tboxOwner');
  var dboxDeadline = app.createDateBox()
      .setFormat(UiApp.DateTimeFormat.DATE_SHORT)
      .setId('dboxDeadline').setName('dboxDeadline');

  gridActionItems.setWidget(0, 0, lblTaskStatement);
  gridActionItems.setWidget(0, 1, tboxTask);

  gridActionItems.setWidget(1, 0, lblOwner);
  gridActionItems.setWidget(1, 1, tboxOwner);

  gridActionItems.setWidget(2, 0, lblDeadline);
  gridActionItems.setWidget(2, 1, dboxDeadline);

  var btnAdd = app.createButton('Add');

  var lblTest = app.createLabel().setId('lblTest').setVisible(false);

  panelActionItems.add(gridActionItems)
    .add(btnAdd).add(lblTest);

  app.add(panelActionItems);

  addHandler = app.createServerHandler('_responseToAdd')
    .addCallbackElement(panelActionItems);

  btnAdd.addClickHandler(addHandler);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.show(app);
}


// add response to a separate tab and close the UI
function _responseToAdd(e) {

  // store user's inputs;
  var actionItems = [];

  var actionObject = new Object();

  var taskStatement = e.parameter.tboxTask;
  var owner = e.parameter.tboxOwner;
  var deadline = e.parameter.dboxDeadline;

  actionObject['task'] = taskStatement;
  actionObject['owner'] = owner;
  actionObject['deadline'] = deadline;

  actionItems.push(actionObject);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Action Items");

  var headers = ['task', 'owner', 'deadline'];

  var valuesR = ObjApp.objectToArray(headers, actionItems); //returns [[]]
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, valuesR[0].length).setValues([valuesR[0]]);

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var panelActionItems = app.getElementById('panelActionItems');
  panelActionItems.clear();

  return app;


}
```

Comment: I prefer to use the code described here

http://stackoverflow.com/a/13128177/1391230

Sergi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do it using multiple panels like in [this post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661146/replicate-tab-panel-in-gui-builder-google-apps/11669914#11669914), you could build the panels and change their content depending of the answers...

Comment: Since I don't know how to create my first UI using the GUI Builder, I'm not sure how to use the multiple panels you suggested.  I have tried that with UI created by code and it doesn't seem to work.  I am currently doing a roundabout way of using a tabpanel instead.

Comment: Using GUI builder or code doesn't change anything... [this app](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxquizfGo85vdeaN7_qss2-LY--UxSLFFeF5ML5rXPWZfrX9oNt/exec) in build entirely with [code](https://script.google.com/d/1aL_y6ZqrfqrzhDZ4yzxM9Ax5hGi9KOHR0ltZ-7gVOTpQCDXV9zY3Ka_Y/edit)